# Media queries doesnt work on phones

Tags: html, css, media, responsive

I have problem with media queries (first time use).
http://swiatek.org.pl/-2/
They are working when I'm changing browser window, but when I'm looking inspect toggle device toolbar on chrome media queries doesnt work :(.
CSS: http://swiatek.org.pl/-2/main.css

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, rather than just posting a link? See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1016716). Also, tell us what exactly doesn't work. "It doesn't work" is not a very good problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px)
```

with

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)
```

and replace

```
@media screen and (max-width: 880px)
```

with

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 880px)
```

Answer (score 0):

add the word "only" when declaring media screens.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 880px) {
    #first header{
        font-size: 55px;
    }
}
```

You can learn more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the meta tag, add this in your header.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`